# How to return value from coroutine / wait for coroutine to finish

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I wrote function to return value from database, it works because i assign value to state and recomposition, but that is not proper way to interact with database.

```
      fun getUser():State<User?>{
        val id = sharedPrefs?.getString("uId", "")
        id?.let {
            if (it != "")
                runBlocking {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        repository?.getUser(it)?.let {
                            currentUser.value = it
                            Log.v("user_1",""+it)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        Log.v("user_2",""+currentUser.value)
        return currentUser
    }
```

I thought runBlocking will make it work, but user_1 contains value and user_2 is null.
So changes are visible only in coroutine which seems to be performed after return.
I would be grateful if you can provide any good resource about coroutines.

Comment: Cheers :) I don't have a solution, but there's a couple of things I see in your code style which might actually cause the issue. Hence, if I may:

Comment: Depending on how much "proper" solution do you need. Ideally, `getUser()` should be a suspend function and you should remove both `runBlocking()` and `launch()`. If `repository.getUser()` is a suspend function, you don't need to switch to `IO` as well, so your almost whole function becomes just: `return repository.getUser(it)`. Alternatively, you could not return the user, but run the code that needs it directly from this function. The easiest, but the worst solution is to still use `runBlocking()`. Just remove `launch()` inside and it should work. But you can't use this inside the main thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use a suspend function and `withContext` instead of `launch` -- there are several other things I'd clean up in your code (eliminate almost all the `?.let`), but this should do:

```
   suspend fun getUser():State<User?>{
        val id = sharedPrefs?.getString("uId", "")
        id?.let {
            if (it != "")
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        repository?.getUser(it)?.let {
                            currentUser.value = it
                            Log.v("user_1",""+it)
                        }
                }
        }
        Log.v("user_2",""+currentUser.value)
        return currentUser
    }
```